# Calling MainActivity method from other classes (which extend broadcast receiver)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to call the method display_notification of MainActivity from other class (PhoneStateReceiver).

**But got this error:**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.weekendproject.roshu.spamblocker.PhoneStateReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

*Error was specially pointed to this line in MainActivity*

**Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);**

However i tried to change `getApplicationContext()` into `"this"` and `"getActivity()"`, But its not working

Here is the **complete code**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void display_notification(String incoming_number) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action)
                    .setContentTitle("SpamBlocker alert !!")
                    .setContentText("SpamBlocker blocked number : " + incoming_number);

    // **Error occured in following line**
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand = r.nextInt(1000);
    mNotificationManager.notify(rand, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**PhoneStateReceiver.java**

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MainActivity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mActivity = new MainActivity();
        mActivity.display_notification(incomingNumber);           // call main activity methods

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the **context provided by onReceive**. Try passing that context to display_notification rather than using the activity's context which might not be running at the time you receive broadcast.

So **Change the method signature** to this:

```
 public void display_notification(String incoming_number, Context context)
```

And, pass the context from onReceive like this:

```
 mActivity.display_notification(incomingNumber, context);
```

And use this context when you pass it to Intent like this:

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
```

**EDITED**

Either put the entire method in **receiver** and use the context provided by **onReceive**

OR,

Change that line to this:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Important part is, **context.getSystemService**, where the context is from onReceive.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i modified it.
However i'm getting error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()" 
this error occured in this line "NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);"

Comment: Right, so ultimately you have to put the method, display_notification in the broadcast receiver because the activity is not yet created and the system services are being used. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.MainActivity");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    context.startActivity(i);﻿
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea to new an Activity object, otherwise the lifecycle won't be maintained properly, and its fields may be null, which could cause NPE.
I suggest you move your Notification builder into a util class, the detail code may be similar to @dhun's answer.
By the way, making the util method of this util class static is not a good practice, because it'll make your code hard to unit test. More details in the [Google Testing Blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a beginner to android app dev. can you please show some links on "how we can put it in util class"

Answer (score 1):

You're implementing your `Activity` and `BroadcastReceiver` backwards. the receiver should be a member of your activity, not vice-versa. Also, you should never call `new MainActivity()` explicitly like that. Android does this internally, and includes some system and app related info with the call (like package name!). Try this instead:

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    PhoneStateReceiver mReceiver

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // create the new receiver, passing MainActivity as an argument
        mReceiver = new PhoneStateReceiver(this);

        // initialize the filter. this is like a letterbox, it lets android
        // know where to send your broadcast
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("NUMBER_BLOCKED");  // P.O. box NUMBER_BLOCKED
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    public void display_notification(String incoming_number) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action)
                        .setContentTitle("SpamBlocker alert !!")
                        .setContentText("SpamBlocker blocked number : " + incoming_number);

        // **Error occured in following line**
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Random r = new Random();
        int rand = r.nextInt(1000);
        mNotificationManager.notify(rand, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

***PhoneStateReceiver.java***

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MainActivity mActivity;

    public PhoneStateReceiver(MainActivity activity) {
        super();

        // store the activity from MainActivity.onCreate()
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // retrieve INCOMING_NUMBER from the broadcast
        String number = intent.getStringExtra("INCOMING_NUMBER");
        mActivity.display_notification(number);
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what's going on in the app that *sends* the broadcast, but I get the feeling that this might still not work. If you're still getting errors, post the full code for both apps.